# Why are "what do I charge" questions permitted?

Tags: discussion, questions, vote-to-close

A [quick search](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion%20charge) shows roughly 80-90 questions asking about how or what to charge in some manner. (loosely filtering for not-so-relevant search results)

That's nearly 20% of all questions. 20%!

I don't see how *any* of these questions could definitively be answered ever. There are far, far too many variables which go into the rates someone can specifically change. In addition a community discussing what to charge for common services could easily be construed as "price fixing" by someone who wished to instigate something I realize it would be a stretch based on current questions. Nonetheless that line does exist.

So, since it's **impossible** to ever definitively, or even effectively, answer the "what do I charge for XXXX" why aren't these question closed more?

These are simply are bad questions. I understand the desire of users to have someone spoon-feed them what they should be pricing things at but A stack beta full of bad questions is just as unlikely to graduate as a beta missing questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Proposed close reason: (Editable community wiki):**

> Questions asking us to set a price for you is off-topic. We can't tell you *what* to set as a price; however, we *can* tell you *how* to set a price. See [Is there a pattern we use to set our price?](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/663/is-there-a-pattern-we-can-use-to-increase-our-price-along-with-experience) If this doesn't answer the question of *how* to set a price *for your unique situation*, please edit this post to add more details.

Comment: I created a proposed close reason to cover these cases. The question I linked to is one I randomly grabbed that seems to cover the question of *how*. There may be a better question to link to, if necessary. This is also a community wiki post to make it easier for others to contribute.

Comment: I like that close reason as-is.

Answer (score 3):

We can definitely take a more assertive role in closing these. I agree they're not the best questions, and their utility won't last long, since the market prices change over time.

Since this is a commonly asked question, we could also look around and see if we have a good canonical post that explains *how* to set one's price.  we can include that in the close reason.  Just because we can't tell a user *exactly* what to charge doesn't mean they can't leave with some helpful information that already exists on our site.

Answer (score 2):

I agree. That's why I close a majority of the questions I do see asking how much to charge.

I have purposely left open some questions that I feel fit the se model of "teach a man to fish". Unless someone can give the community a reason to keep them open. I'd say we make it off topic, and close such questions.